# Using XSLT to put a wrapping element around XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a file like this -

```
<item>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>Bob</name>
</item>
<item>
    <id>6</id>
    <name>Harry</name>
</item>
```

I'd like to wrap it around with something like "items" so it looks like this

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Bob</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>6</id>
        <name>Harry</name>
    </item>
</items>
```

If possible I'd prefer a general solution so it works with tags other than "id" and "name". Is this possible through XSLT?

Comment: This will not work with xlst, because your input XML is  not well formed (missing root element).

Comment: Try posting ALL you real XML.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping element with XSLT in general is not a big deal. But with your input this will not work.

XSLT required **well formed XML** as input and your XML is not well formed because of the missing top level element.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most creative solution, but it should wrap it.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
    </items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Attribute @select is not allowed on element <xsl:copy>"

Comment: You're right.  I haven't done XSLT in a while.  I think the `select="."` is implied in `<xsl:copy />`